# How do I add fields such as Requires, License, and Summary in an RPM created by install4j?

Tags: install4j

I've noticed that the .rpm created by install4j doesn't seem to be completely valid, which some repository managers require. The main fields I'd need to edit are Requires, License, and Summary.

Is there an easy way to do this via JVM-based tools? It would be nice to avoid a build step that requires running on a RPM-oriented Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three fields are not supported by install4j as of 6.0. I've created an issue for it.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround, at least for me, was to create a script to generate a basic rpm spec, and launch `rpmbuild --buildroot=... -bb [spec]`. It's far from pretty and requires running on machine with `rpmbuild` installed on it. (The RPM build process is a little strange.)

Just for posterity, the spec I've created looks like

```
Name: ...
Version: ...
Release: ...
Summary: ...
License: ...
Distribution: ...
Group: ...
Packager: ...
Requires: ...

%description
...

%files
...

%post
...
```

There's clearly more that's possible with RPMs, but it generally does everything that I need, and it was less than clear on what to do.

So... it's a workaround for my process, though it sure will be easier to automate when I can basically control most of the basic metadata in a single install4j build. :)